# How realistic is using same ammo crate for different guns in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, gotham

On a recent episode on Gotham, Oswald(Penguin) is making 9mm ammunition. Gordon and Bullock are in a gun fight and eventually run out of ammo.

We can see in the next scene there is a cartridge can of ammo being brought in, to re supply Gordon, who is using a semi automatic at the scene. Gordon reaches in the box and reloads his semi auto.

However, it seems like that Bullock is using a .38 snub nosed revolver and he **also** reloads from the same ammo can.(from same 9mm ammo).

Did the screen writer screw up?  I've never seen a snub nosed .38 use 9mm ammo.

How much of this Bullock's actions is real? Is it possible to his gun to use 9mm ammo or is there something else that I've missed?

Comment: For the close vote, this is not a trivia question

Comment: Well, at the very least it's a rather useless "Look, I found this movie mistake!" post, though.